# Gwt And Amazon S3 Integration getting error

Tags: gwt, amazon-s3

```
 package com.wa.test.client;

 import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
 import com.nubotech.gwt.oss.client.OnlineStorageService;
 import com.nubotech.gwt.oss.client.OnlineStorageServiceFactory;
 import com.nubotech.gwt.oss.client.auth.Credential;

 public class TestAmazon implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    Credential credential = new Credential("xyz@gmail.com", "QFTG8an1yTB");
    OnlineStorageService storageService = OnlineStorageServiceFactory.getService(credential);
    storageService.createBucket("myFirstBucket");

  }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='testamazon'>
<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
<inherits name='com.nubotech.gwt.oss.Oss'/>

<!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
<!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
<!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

<!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

<!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
<entry-point class='com.wa.test.client.TestAmazon'/>

<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
<source path='client'/>
<source path='shared'/>

![enter image description here][1]</module>
```

This is my code and also include jar file `gwt-s3-api-0.9.3`.
Its give an error as follow:

```
12:40:38.347 [ERROR] [testamazon] Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/Technologies/Java/Amazon/jar/
gwt-s3-api-0.9.3.jar!/com/nubotech/gwt/oss/client/s3/MockS3OnlineStorageService.java'

[ERROR] [testamazon] - Line 28: The import com.google.gwt.user.client.HTTPRequest 
cannot be resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using mismatched version of jars. com.google.gwt.user.client.HTTPRequest was available in older version of GWT gwt-servlet.jar and gwt-user.jar . It got deprecated in GWT 1.5 and in latest GWT it is eliminated. You should be using GWT RequestBuilder.

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.http.HTTP'/>
```

In Java code.

```
import com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder
```

Reference - http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/HTTPRequest.html

The third party jar you are using is very old and not updated for 3 years.

**In your case the [MockS3OnlineStorageService.java](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-s3/source/browse/trunk/main/src/com/nubotech/gwt/oss/client/s3/MockS3OnlineStorageService.java) inside the gwt-s3-api-0.9.3.jar is using HTTPRequest class which is no longer supported in GWT 2.4**

Comment: i had already done this things. But still having same problem as above.

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using?

Comment: You cannot use gwt-s3-api-0.9.3.jar with GWT 2.4 . You can fork gwt-s3-api and sanitize/upgrade it to make it compatible with latest GWT before using it in your project.